# ZooKeeper error while installing Confluent

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I have installed Confluent-7.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 following the official documentation. I have added the path of `confluent_home` as shown below in `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/home/abc/confluent-7.0.0/bin:$PATH 
export PATH=$PATH:$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin
```

And run the command source  `~/.bashrc`. Now the problem is when I have started my services first time by Confluent local services start it has up the services of ZooKeeper, Kafka, schema registry, kafka-rest, connect and ksql and control center. And setup `zookeper.properties` after that I restarted Confluent local services start its giving the error:

The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only, NOT for production usage. See more: https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html
As of Confluent Platform 8.0, Java 8 is no longer supported.

```
Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.639709
Starting ZooKeeper
Error: ZooKeeper failed to start
```

Comment: Use `zookeeper-server-start` manually. Look at the errors reported... Also, latest Kafka version doesn't need Zookeeper, so try upgrading